# Ява и выделение памяти - я знаю, что ничего не знаю.

Tags: java

Доброго всем выходного дня!
В отличии от Сократа я понял, что я реально ничего не знаю.
Взялся пройти тест по основам Java и по получению результата содрогнулся. Заинтересовал один вопрос. Собственно простейший код с иерархией:

```
class ClassA{
    public String text = "from A";

    public void setText( String text ) { this.text = text; }

    public String getText() { return text; }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA{
    public String text = "from B";

    public void setText( String text ) { this.text = text; }

    public String getText() { return text; }
}
```

Где-то в "дебрях" public static void:

```
ClassB classB = new ClassB();
ClassA classA = classB;  // (4)
//classA.setText( "from A" );  // (2)
classA.text = "from A";  // (3)

// вывод
System.out.println( "classA.text:\t" + classA.text );  // (1)
System.out.println( "classB.text:\t" + classB.text );

System.out.println( "getTextA:\t" + classA.getText() );
System.out.println( "getTextB:\t" + classB.getText() );
```

Собственно вывод очевиден - везде, кроме строки (1) будет выдано "трам-пам-пам: from B".
Но если откомментировать (2) и закомментить (3), то ВЕЗДЕ в выводе будет "трам-пам-пам: from A".
Так вот вопрос: где же в первом случае будет в памяти располагаться поле "text" объекта "classA", содержащий значение "from A"?
Что происходит после выполнения строки (4)?
Если можно, ответьте поподробнее)

Comment: Недавно такой же по сути вопрос обсуждался: http://hashcode.ru/questions/266434/

Comment: спасибо большое, но я хотел бы узнать именно где в памяти будет располагаться, и как там будет все вариться.

Comment: @nightin_gale: вам не должно хотеться это знать. Насколько я понимаю, это не определено стандартом, а значит, каждый компилятор имеет право реализовывать это по-своему.

Достаточно знать _смысл_ виртуального вызоваЮ отличие compile-time- от runtime-связывания.

Comment: хорошо)) мне уже не хочется) спасибо)

Comment: @nightin_gale, расположение в памяти полей `text` в классах `ClassA` и `ClassB` не меняется. Где что было в первом случае, то там же и осталось во втором.

Разница в том, к какому из полей `text` (`ClassA` или `ClassB`) Вы обращаетесь.

--

Собственно из-за подобных "непоняток" и надо по возможности **избегать наследования**.

Comment: Совет "избегать наследования" большая глупость и по всей видимости тяжёлое наследие чистого С

Comment: @AndrewFrolov, видимо это только у меня, но и у автора "Философия Java". Б. Эккель по поводу выбора между наследованием и *композицией* пишет:

    Наследование на практике применяется реже. Поэтому, хотя во время изучения ООП наследованию уделяется очень много внимания, это не значит, что его следует без разбора применять всюду, где это возможно. Наоборот, пользоваться им следует осмотрительно - только там, где полезность наследования не вызывает сомнений...

На самом же деле - просто обидно потратить много сил на изучение какой-то вещи, а потом узнать, что без нее все получается проще.

Comment: Уважаемый Б. Эккель пишет совсем не так категорично, и советует применять его там, где "полезность наследования не вызывает сомнений". Согласитесь, это ну совсем не то же самыое, что и заявлять "надо по возможности избегать наследования". Эккель советует применять, вы советуете избегать.

Comment: Ну еще бы **для Java** категорически отвергать наследование. Да и я советую не применять **по возможности**. 

Но лучше, если нет крайней необходимости  использовать чужой *закрытый* код - да, избегать. 

Кстати, никогда не задумывались о внутренней противоречивости ООП?

Например, поразмышляйте о появлении рефлексии (IMHO последствие увлечения инкапсуляцией) и том, куда ведет этот путь.

Вспоминается старая шутка - "автомобиль это страшное оружие в руках молодого бойца".

Comment: Угу, очень часто композицию необоснованно заменяют наследованием даже там, где она не нужна, просто для повторного использования кода.

В этом отношении мне нравится принцип Smalltalk'а: там, насколько я понимаю, наследование интерфейсов и использование общего кода — полностью независимые друг от друга вещи.

Отношение наследования должно быть выражением зависимости типа `is a`, и конечно должен выполняться принцип L из [SOLID](http://bit.ly/KsZplW).

Comment: Частая ситуация, когда одна-две ошибки ведут к созданию мифа. Давайте правильно расставим акценты, чтоб не плодить таких мифов в неокрепших умах местных студентов :) Есть новички, которые делают детские ошибки и применяют наследование там, где нет отношения is a. Есть новички, которые применяют reflection для того, чтобы обойти инкапсуляцию. Но это не значит, что reflection зло и наследование не надо использовать.

Comment: @AndrewFrolov: Если бы одна-две! Люди, даже всю жизнь пишущие на плюсах или Java, часто не понимают суть ООП, от этого и допускают детские ошибки и после сдачи диплома. Я убеждён, что казалось бы тривиальные вещи надо явно проговаривать.

Answer (score 2):

По ссылке выше всё правильно сказали. Вот описание этого поведения в стандарте.

[Field Access Using a Primary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1)